# Using Spring for DI with Annotations in a Portlet without using DisplatcherPortlet

Tags: spring, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I have a huge set of really old Portlets code I am being required to "refactor" due to a bug that was found in Prod.  The refactor is requiring me to update to a new library, and as a result move from a custom DAO structure using "Query" classes to one that uses Springs JdbcTemplate and annotations to wire everything together.

BUT, there are a LOT of portlets.  Is there a way to use Spring with Annotations for DI that does NOT require me to completely re-write the Portlet to use `DispatcherPortlet` and the `@RequestMapping`s?  I just want to mark all the Portlets, and the handful of Servlets as well, with `@Component` just to have Spring inject the classes I need.  Where I am struggling is in how to bootstrap the `ApplicationContext` without using the Spring-provided dispatcher portlet/servlet to initiate the context.  I would like to not have to use the `ApplicationContext` directly to pull the necessary beans out by hand, if possible.  I do have `contextConfigLocation` and the `ContextLoaderListener` defined in my web.xml already.

Comment: When using the `DispatcherPortlet` you aren't forced to use annotations at all. The mapping is done with a `HandlerMapping` and you could use/configure one that uses plain Portlet, which allows to have your basic portlets configured by spring and the `DispatcherPortlet` is used for delegation.

Comment: Can you point me to some docs?  We are on Spring 3.0.6, if that matters.

Comment: Both the `DispatcherServlet` and `DispatcherPortlet` can be put in front of respectively a `Servlet` or `Portlet`. This would also allow you to use the `HandlerInterceptor` to pre-proces the request for instance. For portlets I suggest a read of the corresponding chapter in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#portlet). Especially the [`PortletWrappingController`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#portlet-controller-wrapping) is something you probably want.

Comment: I guess where I am struggling is that I don't quite understand how the DispatcherPortlet knows which portlet to run on a request.  Most of the examples we have of Spring-based portlets, there is only a single portlet per WAR.  But in this code there is like 10 separate portlets.  Also, I am not sure how to add the portlets in without going through ALL the code and adding `@RequestMapping`s all over the place.  That's the part I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Please read the documentation. The portlet uses a `HandlerMapping` to determine which portlet to execute. The `@RequestMapping` is just one way of mapping requests and depends on the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` however there are others (as explained in the reference guide).